# Design consideration for designing mega menu for custom CMS in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database-design, content-management-system, megamenu

What is the best practice that can be following in designing a custom CMS which can handle Mega Menus structure, I am not able to find an example which can clearly show with example database design of CMS.

I would appreciate if some can point me to a good resource which has example of database design along with source code in asp.net web form i can be flexible with database.

It is easy to design MegaMenu if all the menu are stored in one table. In some case i have to construct Mega Menus from different Table let us take for example following main menus

Home  | Article  | News | About Us | Contact Us

I want to structure my menus in such a way so that it can read menu details from different table like

Article Menu: Top 3 article with image

News Menu: Top 3 News with image

Contact Us Menu: Should show show link to offices in different countries like USA, Canada, Germany, India, England in two or 3 columns.

So far i have not found any useful example which can be used as learning purpose which shows the base architecture design of CMS with different feature like News, products (which are different in nature for example)

I tried to study wordpress which actually store pages/post in one table and assign the value type post or page to differentiate but in some case we need to have different things like products which need to be store in different table. I am confused how to create a Mega Menu system which can read menus information from different table rather than create a Separte menu table which can be a real headache if one had hundred of products. In such approach we have to update the product related tables as well as menu table which is not a good design approach.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you go for a single table approach:

See this one I just made on dbpatterns: http://dbpatterns.com/show//509bbcae89cbad253a2f5717/

So now content wise

```
Example

ID: 1
Title: Article
item_link: home.aspx
parent: null
order: 1

ID: 2
Title: Article
item_link: page.aspx
parent: null
order: 2

ID: 3
Title: Article Number 1
item_link: page1.aspx
parent: 1 (ID of Article)
order: 1


ID: 4
Title: Article Number 2
item_link: page2.aspx
parent: 2 (ID of Article)
order: 2

ID: 5
Title: Article Number 3
item_link: page3.aspx
parent: 2 (ID of Article)
order: 3


ID: 6
Title: News
item_link: News.aspx
parent: null
order: 3

ID: 7
Title: News Number 1
item_link: News1.aspx
parent: 6 (ID of News)
order: 1


ID: 8
Title: News Number 2
item_link: News2.aspx
parent: 6 (ID of News)
order: 2

ID: 9
Title: News Number 3
item_link: News3.aspx
parent: 6 (ID of News)
order: 3
```

So when you build the menu code side you get all the items

Loop through each item with no parent to build top level, then through each item with a parent, add to parent item, and ordering them by the Order (note the order is per sub menu).

Note on ordering: Top level items go 1,2,3,4 etc...

Sub menu items also go 1,2,3 but for the menu item they are within.

Comment: Thanks, I had though of similar approach didn't implement it so far as i then need to create Another Table 'Menus` & design it in similar fashion. I guess i might have to create it the same way. I looked at word-press they also create pages separately & menus separately.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very, very vague - but if you want a mega menu in a .Net CMS, you could look at Umbraco, with the LocalGov extension (http://kevin.thejumps.co.uk/2011/umbraco-localgov/). Even if you don't use it, you can see how others have implemented this functionality.

Comment: I agree with you regarding the question but the topic is so wide it is difficult to document everything. What i am looking for is a CMS architecture or core engine around which one can build or customize CMS with different  section like News, Gallery, Media Centre, Events, Booking Section which may be different in nature from each other...